# Prove that the integral of P_n(x)P_m(x) on [-1,1] is 0

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

From Introduction to Calculus and Analysis I by Richard Courant and Fritz John. Problem: Let $$P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}((x^2-1)^n)$$
Show that $$\int_{-1}^{1}P_n(x)P_m(x)=0 \;\;\text{if $m\ne n$} $$

My work:

First, I evaluated (or tried to evaluate) $$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}((x^2-1)^n)$$

I applied binomial theorem to the function to be differentiated and got:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}(-1)^{n-i} x^{2i}$$

Differentiating a few times gives me

$$\frac{d}{dx}((x^2-1)^n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{i}(2i)(-1)^{n-i} x^{2i-1}$$

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}((x^2-1)^n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{i}(2i)(2i-1)(-1)^{n-i} x^{2i-2}$$

Hence I find the following expressions: for n an even number and m an odd number,

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}((x^2-1)^n)=\sum_{i=n/2}^{n}\binom{n}{i}(2i)(2i-1) ...(2i-n+1)(-1)^{n-i} x^{2i-n}$$
$$\frac{d^m}{dx^m}((x^2-1)^m)=\sum_{i=(m+1)/2}^{m}\binom{n}{i}(2i)(2i-1) ...(2i-m+1)(-1)^{m-i} x^{2i-m}$$

I noticed that $P_n(x)$ is an even function, while $P_m(x)$ is an odd function. Hence $\int_{-1}^{1}P_n(x)P_m(x)=0.$ But if n and m are both even or both odd, then $P_n(x)P_m(x)$ will be an even function, so $\int_{-1}^{1}P_n(x)P_m(x)\ne 0$. How may I proceed in this case?

EDIT: I don't want to use advanced linear algebra concepts or formulas to solve this, nor do I expect the use of Taylor series. And certainly no differential equations, please.

Comment: $P_n$ is called Legendre polynomial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show this without doing much explicit calculations at all. You just need to do a bit of integration by parts and know some basic facts about polynomials.

Writing out what the integral means we get the complicated expression

$$\frac{1}{2^nn!2^mm!}\int_{-1}^1\left[\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n\right]\cdot\left[\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(x^2-1)^m\right]{\rm d}x$$

First notice that $(x^2-1)^n = (x-1)^n(x+1)^n$ is a polynomial of degree $2n$ that has a zero of degree $n$ at both $x=1$ and $x=-1$. This means that all the first $n-1$th derivatives of this function will also have a zero at $x=\pm 1$. This fact will be important for us when we do integration by parts below as it will ensure that the boundary term will vanish.

Now recall integration by parts: $\int_{-1}^1 uv'dx = [uv]_{-1}^1 - \int_{-1}^1 vu'dx$. Note that if the boundary term $uv$ is zero at $x=\pm 1$ then we simply have $\int_{-1}^1 uv'dx = -\int_{-1}^1 vu'dx$. This is very useful as it allows us to easily "transfer" derivatives from one term to the other (it just gives rise to a change of sign).

We can now perform the argument. Assuming that $m>n$ we transfer $n$ of the $m$-derivatives over to the other term using integration by part $n$ times in a row. From the discussion above this simply gives

$$(-1)^n\frac{1}{2^nn!2^mm!}\int_{-1}^1\left[\frac{d^{n+n}}{dx^{n+n}}(x^2-1)^n\right]\cdot\left[\frac{d^{m-n}}{dx^{m-n}}(x^2-1)^m\right]{\rm d}x$$

The factor of $(-1)^n$ comes from the $n$ sign changes we get from the integration by part. Now since $(x^2-1)^n$ is a polynomial of degree $2n$ then the $n+n=2n$ derivative of this expression will just be a constant! So we are left with the integral of the $m-n$ derivative of $(x^2-1)^m$. This integral is just the $m-n-1$ derivative of $(x^2-1)^m$ evaluated at $x=\pm 1$ which we know is zero.

Now what happens for $n=m$? After transfering over $n$ derivatives there are no more left (the last term is simply $(x^2-1)^m$) so the final integral is no longer the integral of a derivative and the argument fails (which is good as the result is in fact non-zero).

Comment: I got a different formula as yours using integration by parts: int_{-1}^{1} (d^n(x^2-1)^n/dx^n)(d^m(x^2-1)^n/dx^m)dx = -int_{-1}^{1}d^{m-k}(x^2-1)^n/dx^{m-k} d(d^{n-k}(x^2-1)^n/dx^{n-k}). Is this equivalent to yours or also valid?

Comment: @Divide1918 Here is some more details. Let $(\cdot)^{(n)}$ denote the $n$th derivative of whatever is inside the brackets. When we do integration by parts we get $\int (\cdot)^{(n)}(\cdot)^{(m)} = (-1)\int (\cdot)^{(n+1)}(\cdot)^{(m-1)}$ Then we do it again to get $= (-1)^2\int (\cdot)^{(n+2)}(\cdot)^{(m-2)}$ ...and again to get $= (-1)^3\int (\cdot)^{(n+3)}(\cdot)^{(m-3)}$ and so on. This will give a factor $(-1)^n$ after you have done it $n$ times.

Comment: Which one do you set to be dv in the form of IBP \int u dv=uv-\int v du?

Comment: The first time I set $u = \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$ and $v' = \frac{d^m}{dx^m}(x^2-1)^m$ so that $v = \frac{d^{m-1}}{dx^{m-1}}(x^2-1)^m$. Then $u' = \frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}(x^2-1)^n$

Comment: Oh sorry, I made some typos in my first comment so you might wanna refer to my latest edit.

Comment: Your formula is not correct as you have decreased the derivative on both terms $m-k$ and $n-k$ while it should be $m-k$ and $n+k$. Secondly you are missing the $(-1)^k$ factor (not that it matters since the result is zero, but it should be there if you did it correctly)

Comment: That was what I did, but the second time I just take \int v u' to be my LHS of the IBP formula and then I calculated that m and n drops by 1 for every 2 applications of IBP, and hence I got only negative.

Answer (score 1):

These are called [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials).

You're looking for a proof that any two distinct Legendre polynomials are *orthogonal*. This is quite a standard proof, you can see one in these notes I wrote [here](https://drmenguin.com/files/legendre.pdf#subsection.4.2):

[image]

Comment: Dear Luke, the link above does not work to me (maybe it needs an update).

Answer (score 0):

This type of polynomials has the name "Associated Legendre Polynomials". The proof of the orthogonality can be found, for example, here

[Associated Legendre Polynomials Orthogonality Proof: $\int_{-1}^1 P_k^m(x) \cdot P_l^m(x) \; \mathrm{d} x = \frac{2(l+m)!}{(2l+1)(l-m)!} \delta_{k,l}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737301/associated-legendre-polynomials-orthogonality-proof-int-11-p-kmx-cdot)